# passenger-install-apache2-module fails

Tags: ruby, apache, rubygems, centos, passenger

My server has this SO: Centos Linux 2.6.32-042stab084.1 x86_64

I've done:

```
yum -y install ruby rubygems

yum -y install zlib-devel curl-devel openssl-devel httpd-devel apr-devel apr-util-devel mysql-devel gcc ruby-devel

yum -y install gcc-c++ make postgresql-devel ImageMagick-devel sqlite-devel perl-LDAP mod_perl perl-Digest-SHA

gem install passenger
```

Then I do:

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

But I get this trace:

Sanity checking Apache installation...
All good!

```
--------------------------------------------
Compiling and installing Apache 2 module...
cd /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/passenger-4.0.37
# /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/wrappers/rake RELEASE=yes apache2:clean apache2
rm -rf buildout/cache
rm -rf buildout/common/libboost_oxt.a buildout/common/libboost_oxt
rm -f buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Logging.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Exceptions.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/SystemTime.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/StrIntUtils.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/IOUtils.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils.o
rm -f buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/Base64.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/CachedFileStat.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/LargeFiles.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/ApplicationPool2/Implementation.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/ApplicationPool2/AppTypes.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/AgentsStarter.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/AgentsBase.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/MD5.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/fib.o buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/jsoncpp.o
rm -f buildout/common/libpassenger_common/agents/LoggingAgent/FilterSupport.o
rm -rf buildout/common/libpassenger_common
rm -rf buildout/agents/
rm -rf buildout/apache2/module_libboost_oxt.a buildout/apache2/module_libboost_oxt
rm -f buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Logging.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Exceptions.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils/SystemTime.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils/StrIntUtils.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils/IOUtils.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils.o
rm -f buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils/Base64.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils/CachedFileStat.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils/LargeFiles.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/ApplicationPool2/Implementation.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/ApplicationPool2/AppTypes.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/AgentsStarter.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/AgentsBase.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils/MD5.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils/fib.o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Utils/jsoncpp.o
rm -f buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/agents/LoggingAgent/FilterSupport.o
rm -rf buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common
rm -rf buildout/apache2/Configuration.o buildout/apache2/Bucket.o buildout/apache2/Hooks.o buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.o buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
mkdir -p buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common
c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -fPIC -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/apr-1 -I/usr/include/apr-1 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/include/httpd -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -feliminate-unused-debug-symbols -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAVE_ACCEPT4 -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_MAP_HEADER="<hash_map>" -DHASH_MAP_CLASS="hash_map" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Logging.o -c ext/common/Logging.cpp
c++: Error interno: `Terminado (killed)' (programa cc1plus)
Por favor envíe un reporte completo de bichos.
Vea <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> para más instrucciones.
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [c++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -fPIC -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/apr-1 -I/usr/include/apr-1 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/include/httpd -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fcommon -feliminate-unused-debug-symbols -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -g -DHAS_ALLOCA_H -DHAVE_ACCEPT4 -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_MAP_HEADER="<hash_map>" -DHASH_MAP_CLASS="hash_map" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -o buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Logging.o -c ext/common/Logging.cpp]
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/passenger-4.0.37/build/cplusplus_support.rb:51:in `run_compiler'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/passenger-4.0.37/build/cplusplus_support.rb:61:in `compile_cxx'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/passenger-4.0.37/lib/phusion_passenger/common_library.rb:133:in `block (2 levels) in define_category_tasks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => apache2 => buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so => buildout/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/Logging.o
```

What is my problem???
Thanks

Comment: Forget about passenger and apache and get unicorn and nginx. You'll thank me when you get to production.

Comment: @Abdo I am one of the Phusion Passenger authors, and co-founder of Phusion. Perhaps you're suggesting Unicorn because you had bad experiences with Passenger in the past. I apologize for any issues you might have had. Could you perhaps tell me more about the issues? We really value stability and robustness so if there's any way we can help you, we'd be glad to. We are confident that our product performs great in production environments. After all, it's already used by the likes of Apple, Pixar, Juniper, 37signals, etc.  If you could tell me more about your issues, I'll have a look personally.

Comment: @Hongli It's great that you guys care about your reputation =) What made me go with Passenger at first was its ease of installation and configuration (vs that of unicorn + nginx) My experience is not recent (over a 1.5 years ago) and I'm sure you guys have enhanced the product since. The real killer for me was, back then, CPU usage would get really high and the server would start lagging/hanging etc. I spent weeks debugging my code and nothing could fix that (Others were having similar issues - back then). Unicorn + nginx fixed my issues. (I'll elaborate in my next comment)

Comment: If my memory is good, Passenger launched multiple ruby processes, which consumed a lot of CPU & memory given the size of my application. Also, load time was slower than unicorn's. From what I read, Unicorn forks the parent process, enabling it to share memory with its children. What I also like about Unicorn is its capability of restarting the server with new code with 0 downtime (by forking a new process and swapping with old once loaded). Also, Nginx' micro caching has been really helpful during spikes. I've been really happy with nginx+unicorn, this is why I recommend them when I can =)

Comment: Just to be fair, you guys might have the aforementioned features now or you might have had them in the past but I wasn't aware of them =)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Abdo. Indeed, we did have many of those features, even 1.5 years ago. The app preloading thing is what we call [smart spawning](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#spawning_methods_explained). [Many other kinds of improvements](http://vimeo.com/phusionnl/review/85970704/29c734399f) have also been made recently. Usually, if there are CPU and memory problems, then there is a good reason and there are good configuration options to mitigate them. We are continuously improving our documentation and tooling to facilitate that.

Comment: For example, we published a guide about [tuning memory and concurrency](http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/03/12/tuning-phusion-passengers-concurrency-settings/) and a guide about [debugging stuck processes](http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/09/21/the-right-way-to-deal-with-frozen-processes-on-unix/).

Answer (score 1):

How much RAM + swap does your server have? Maybe your server does not have enough virtual memory. That is the most common reason why the compiler gets killed. Try adding some swap space. Make sure that you have at least 1 GB of swap.

Answer (score 0):

With 2GB swap it's going fine.
Thanks.